# Convert to Current Swift Syntax Failed - "No such module" (Swift 4, Xcode 9)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

In Xcode 9, I am trying to do the automatic conversion to Swift 4.
It fails with the following message:

[image]

> **Convert to Current Swift Syntax Failed**
>   Please ensure that all selected targets build successfully with the currently configured Swift version before attempting a migration.

It's complaining of a missing module. But when I do a regular build there are no issues. Not sure if this is relevant, but the module (which Xcode is complaining is missing) was already converted to Swift 4 earlier (in it's own project).

Note: No Cocoapods / Carthage used here.

Note: Two solutions tried (and worked) but do not address the underlying issue.

- One solution is to do the conversion manually (change Swift version to 4 in build setting and apply Fix-Its one by one until no more build errors).
- Another solution is to disable the third party framework (comment out all code where it's used), do the auto-migration, and then re-enable the framework. This could get pretty difficult with bigger projects.

Comment: Please build your project and check if the project is build successfully . Then try to convert

Comment: Pulkit, as mentioned, "But when I do a regular build there are no issues.".

Comment: Refer to this https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift4      Please mention from which version you are converting from

Comment: you can remove the library you are using ...and then try to convert the application..only if you dont have to comment lot of code ...

Comment: For anyone using CocoaPods it might be worth trying to remove "use_modular_headers!" temporarily and replacing it by "use_frameworks!" for the migration.

Answer (score 12):

I can't find any solution yet.

For now I fix manually setting `Swift Language Version`

[image]

After changing from 3.2 to 4.0 I compile and fix errors and warnings manually.
I'm waiting for a better solution!

Answer (score 6):

I also got this problem while converting my project to Swift 4.0. Looks like problem appears when you try to convert target which imports a framework which is already in Swift 4.0. At your screenshot you try to convert  '*RecipeTextParser*' which imports '*SovaTools*' which is already Swift 4.0.

I found dirty, but working solution. You can use older(Swift 3.2) version of '*SovaTools*' when converting. You should **NOT** check it's mark in target selection window of conversion tool. Then, when '*RecipeTextParser*' will be successfully converted you can use Swift 4.0 '*SovaTools*' version again.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error and in my case one of my Pods(the one Xcode was complaining about) was a Swift 4 target and the rest were Swift 3.2. Looking at the build logs it looks like Xcode built that framework in one location and was searching for it in another. When I reverted that Pod to an older version(that used Swift3.2) the problem went away. Obviously a Xcode bug. HTH

Answer (score 3):

Just update your pod and it will resolve the issue.

To update pod:

- open terminal and go to your project directory
- type pod update

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode (Xcode 9) language migration feature is not as much accurate that it can migrate your complete code/project from one swift version to another with zero tolerance. It skips few code migration for us (developers). It may be bug or inaccuracy of tool. But you need to put some manual effort also, to completely migrate swift language version for your project/code.

Now, according to your snapshot, Xcode is showing and error for 'RecipeTextParser' framework. I think this is an external/third party framework. Another point to note, you've integrated this framework using CocoaPods:

Any one of following can be reason for failure of code migration:

1. CocoaPods locks framework (files) for editing. So language migration process may not be able to migrate (or identify) code for external/thirdparty framework.
2. In general terms, Framework is package of code files, so framework itself may not allow file/source code editing.

**Suggestion as solution:**

1. Update your cocoa pods as well as all frameworks integrated using cocoa pods compatible to latest swift language version.
2. If you've manually integrated/added external/third party frameworks, then you need to update/replace those also.

Some manual effort is required to completely migrate code between swift languages. I tried swift migration with above options and my all projects are now compatible with swift 4.