# Importing Xcode project with .xcodeproj file does not work

Tags: xcode, import, project

[image]So the problem is, whenever I try to import my Xcode project, which I did a few months ago (back in may 2018) I get errors on errors.

I zipped the file and put it in a drive while back, only unzipped it and took the `.xcodeproj` to open a new project on Xcode this week. Nothing seems to work. I get storyboard errors and all other type of errors if I try to fix it using the other stackoverflow threads about those errors. Am I doing something wrong?

Shouldn't I just double click on the `.xcodeproj` file and it should work? Does that have to do with a new version of Xcode, and, if so, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't know how we can help you diagnose the errors if you don't share what the errors are. But in answer to your question, yes, you generally can just double click on the `.xcodeproj` file (or, if it's there, the `.xcworkspace`). But if you have a Xcode 9.x project from a few months ago and try to open it in Xcode 10.x, it should generally open without incident. You might want to do the Swift 4.2 conversion, if prompted to do so.

Comment: Yes I am sorry, I was not home so I did not have the error in front of me. I just wanted to know if this is a known issue by any chance! I will try again tonight opening through .xcworkspace! If I get the app from another computer do I have to do anything else than opening the file? Like downloading the rest of the files and put it in a particular emplacement? Thank you very much! I will give the feedback later today!

Comment: The Xcode 10 is a major upgrade, so the Swift 4.2 conversion is definitely more work than usual because lots of method signatures have changed. But the conversion wizard should help. It's not terribly hard, but it is tedious. (I converted a fairly large project, with months of work by a modest-sized team, in 30 min or so.)

Comment: @Rob Hi, so I attached a screenshot showing what's wrong. I can't seem to convert to 4.2. And you can see the two errors on the left of the screen. Which I tried fixing but never worked and kept causing more troubles. I am fairly new to iOS programming and the app is really simple. It was only all the UI I needed and practically no programming in it. Is there an obvious error I don't get? Thanks!

Comment: That’s too bad. You can try some of the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46339426/1271826.

Comment: @Rob thank you, the link did not help me, but I finally updated to 4.2. Now I still have this error that I can't fix: Interface Builder could not open the document Main.storyboard" because it dows not exist. None of the online answers worked... Did this happen to you?

Comment: I’d suggest going back to the original zip file and see if it’s there. I’ve never heard of the `Main.storyboard` just disappearing...

Comment: I've done that at least 5 times from now haha... Always have the same errors happening over and over again...

Comment: You’ve done this five times. So, when you browse the contents of the uncompressed zip file using macOS Finder, do you see a file called `Main.storyboard` anywhere?

Comment: I only see one file which I cannot go in, the .xcodeproj one..